# Side by side div's work only if all have text, or none have text?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have 3 div's side by side, that are inside of a div. It is working for me if they all have text or none of them have text. What i am trying to do is just have the middle one have text, and the other two will have images. If you remove the text from a2 in my fiddle it will look perfect.

http://jsfiddle.net/nPeaV/7138/

```
<div id="a">
<div id="a1" >dd</div>
<div id="a2">dddd<p></p></div>
<div id="a3">d</div>

#a {
height: 118px;
width: 110%;
background-color: yellow;
overflow: hidden;

}
#a1 {
background-color: #F10B78;
width: 12%;
height: 108px;
background-color: red;
display: inline-block;
border: 2.5px solid #FFF5EE;
}
#a2 {


height: 108px;
background-color: pink;
width: 70%;
display: inline-block;
border: 2.5px solid #FFF5EE;
}
#a3 {
width: 12%;
height: 108px;
background-color: red;
display: inline-block;
border: 2.5px solid #FFF5EE;

}
```

Comment: You should add `vertical-align: top;` CSS declaration to all columns. Check the link above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nPeaV/7140/

You need `vertical-align: top` since they're all inline elements:

```
#a1, #a2, #a3 {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Otherwise, the `div` with the text in it would align to what it decides is the current baseline, that is, the bottom of the previous `inline-box`.